# How to properly store data we want to index in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have businesses collection.

The business are reviewed by users.

Each user can only review a business once. Future reviews will simply replace the former one.

This is how we store it

```
 "Reviews" : {
    "gusyanto" : {
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:08 am",
      "review" : "Tes review"
    },
    "sapi" : {
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:18 am",
      "review" : "makanan ini sangat enak"
    }
  }
```

Alternatively we can also use this

```
 "Reviews" : [{
      "userid" : "gusyanto",
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:08 am",
      "review" : "Tes review"
    },
    {
      "userid" : "sapi",
      "day" : "December 21, 2012, 8:18 am",
      "review" : "makanan ini sangat enak"}
    ]
  }
```

So basically we want can store it as a dictionary where the key is the userid or we can store it as an array where userID is the field key. So the key in the second approach is static namely userID.

We want to index the entries. For example, a user may want to know what businesses he has reviewed.

Which approach I should use?

Comment: Can you show me how you do a search for reviews by user 'X', in the 1st case?

Comment: well not exact format but I think it'll be ["Reviews" $in "sapi"] for example?

Answer (score 2):

Well I'd do it like this:

```
                          reviews (collection)
                                  |
                                  |
                    ______________|______________
                   |                             |
                 Doc 1                        Doc 2
  {"user_id": "USer1",                      {"user_id": "USer2",
   "review" : "Tes review",                  "review" : "makanan ini sangat enak",
   "date"   : "December 21, 2012, 8:08 am",  "date"   : "December 21, 2012, 8:08 am",
   "business": "Business1"                   "business": "Business2"
  }                                         }
```

### And then you could build an index as follow:

```
  db.reviews.ensure_index([("user_id", ASCENDING), ("date", ASCENDING)])
  db.reviews.ensure_index([("business", ASCENDING), ("date", ASCENDING)])
```

### Now you can perform queries(in **log(n)** time) such as:

1. Get all reviews for by **User1**  sorted by date.
2. Get reviews for a business sorted by date.

### Update:

Assuming you instead chose to do something like this:

```
                          Businesses (collection)
                                  |
                                  |
                    ______________|______________
                   |                             |
             BusinessDoc 1                    BusinessDoc 2
  {"business": "business1",                      {"user_id": "business",
   "review" : {..business1 reviews here..},     "review" : {..business2 reviews here..},
  }                                         }
```

I will suggest you against putting all the reviews for a business, say "B1" in a single doc, which is what will happen if you have a "Businesses" collection.

#### Why not a 'Business' collection:

1. It'll make your queries and indexes complicated, and
2. If there are just too many reviews for a very popular 'BusinessX', it'll hit the **16MB** limit.

Comment: The collection is the collection of businesses not reviews.

Comment: I would contest the your assumption of hitting the 16meg limit. Most review sites I have seen have 800 reviews. The MongoDB document size can fit the entire works of Shakespeare and still have enough room left for a novel or two. I am uncertain if you are correct about that. Also getting the subdocument would be O(log n) and a single round trip for a business unlike the separate collection proposal. However if the OP needs to display the reviews in a certain way it could effect their ability to embed.

Comment: I know how big is 16MB, but i don't have any idea how many reviews there usually  are or how big are those reviews.

Comment: Well considering you could easily fit 8000 of those docs in 16mb I would say he isn't gonna hit the limit any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take your docs as they are, an example; however, I would like to mention that storing date in string format might hurt your index and querying abilities.

The problem with making an index on the `Reviews` field here is that review content field you have.

I can easily image that being too big for a single index field, in which case an exception will be thrown and it will not be indexed ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Index%20Size and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#indexes-on-sub-documents ). This is probably one of the biggest problems with full text fields in MongoDB.

So with that in mind I already would not advise forming an index on the field itself.

But, as to which index is best is extremely subjective to your querying.

If you were only querying by one field or the other, i.e. `day` or `userid` then I would make two separate indexes, however if you are combining your fields in your queries I would most likely go for a compound edition of the index.

Comment: Storing date in string will be changed. I will store it in timestamp. Basically I wonder which way I should store data. Should the username be key or should it be array?

Comment: @JimThio I would say your second data structure is most appropiate. However both are about the same, one thing I might be able to think of is that querying for a user with the first structure might become difficult in some queries, i.e. `$elemMatch`